# How to get "?android:attr/actionBarSize" with Compatibility Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-compatibility

I'm trying to use Fragments and ActionBar in a Android 2.2 project. There is some error when using "?android:attr/actionBarSize", how to get and set that value correctly?

Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frags">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.hcgallery.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/frag_title"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment class="com.example.android.hcgallery.ContentFragment"
            android:id="@+id/frag_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginTop' with value '?android:attr/actionBarSize').**

Comment: did you found the solution for this? thanks mate!

Answer (score 16):

You should just use:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

> "...The one with the android: prefix is for versions of Android that
>   include the style in the platform and the one without the prefix is
>   for older versions that read the style from the Support Library..."

For me replacing

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

with

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

helped to launch app on Android 2.2 and Android 4.3 without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that actionbar comes with android 3.0 and you are using 2.2. But there is a way to skip this by a extension called "actionbarsherlock".

Comment: So, what did you do to fix the problem? Always answer your questions if you found the answer. It may come handy for future users.